# Disabled footer SSRS with No Row Message

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am working on a SSRS report where I am displaying a NO Row message on a Tablix but I can still see the footer of this report.

Please let me know if there is any way to hide the report footer when there is no rows in the dataset for a given condition.

Thanks

Yogesh

Comment: I have found a way around to deal with this issue. I have changed all the fields mentioned in my footer to be blank when the dataset return an empty result set using the expressions on the fields. I still hope there would a better way to deal with this issue though.

Comment: Did you try an expression in the footer visibility property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Aside from changing all the fields to blank in the footer when your dataset returns empty.
- Another way is to use **Visibility**. Hide all the fields in the footer when the dataset returns empty.

I can only think of these solutions from now based from your scenario.